# Inner functions of Nic

Tags: networking, nic

As packet arrives Nic detect it on its interface like wire/air and than packet is kept in Rx FIFO the on chip memory for further processing like offloading and determining it belong to it after everything using DMA and it's descriptor packet is transmitted to host memory and interrupt is done than kernel manages it.
I understand deeply the code and architecture about how kernel manages packet as have workes on Linux kernel source code.

But the only problem i suffer with is NIC i searched a lot tried to read many books but not got what I wanted to know

That after arriving on wire which is first place where packet stream is kept is it RX FIFO or something else.

Than the details about its every minute processing that it does during working on a particular packet

As it have on chip DMA descriptor as it fetches it from host memory how it allocate packet to particular descriptor

Or leave the above questions as i know some of you will not get it only help i want is to know every minute processing undergoes by NIC from when packet arrives on interface to putting it into host memory can anyone broadly explain it here not in summarised way or suggest link of some webpages/book where I can get what I want

I already posted it on many forums but really the webpages/book i got either told about specification of particular network adapter or summary of Nic processing or about interface between kernel/Host Cpu and Nic

Comment: That's beyond programming and into electronics (and/or opto-electronics, and RF magic depending on how deep you want to go). Research MAC and PHY chips, MII interfaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface).

Comment: You should try to ask on the [electronics.se] SE site.

Comment: @RonMaupin done it hope it works there

Comment: @Mat it's not hardware thing as not all Nic are made up of FPGA some are general CPU and need software codes to perform so I just wanted to know how Nic process packet every minute detail from start to end of handling a packet